# AlwaysOn Availability listener access issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, listener, alwayson

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise edition.

I have created an alwaysOn Availability group on a named instance and configured a listener to it.

When I try to access the listener from SQL Server Management Studio it logs to the default instance.
I configured Endpoint URL to point to the named instance and gave a static port to the instance too

Also note that I have configured endpoints to listen to the same port in both instances.

I have no idea why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping listener name and see what ip you are getting in reply

Answer (score -2):

Use listenername, port to connect in SSMS ( you have to put comma and port number)